# AjaxControlToolkit AnimationExtender - show animation on FormView Insert/Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, formview

In my application, I have a FormView which allows Insert's and Update's. I want to show a message which dissappears after about 2-3 seconds whenever they insert or update. I figured the AnimationExtender from the AjaxControlToolkit would be the best way of doing this, but I can't figure out how to get that animation to fire when a FormView is updated/inserted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling the animation in the [ItemInserted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.iteminserted.aspx) or [ItemUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemupdated.aspx) events for the `FormView`?  That sounds like it would do the trick for you.  They fire every time an Update or Insert occurs from that control.

Alternately, you could just set the `TargetControlID` of your `AnimationExntender` to the id of your Update / Insert button (the one's on your `FormView` with `CommandName` set to "Insert" or "Update"), then just specify your desired animation in the `OnClick` event:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AnimationExtender ID="myAnimExtender"
  runat="server" TargetControlID="updateBtn">
    <Animations>
        <OnClick> ... </OnClick>
    </Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:AnimationExtender>
```

Note that this technique requires you to have two `AnimationExtender`s, one for the Delete button and one for the Update button.